# excel formula for date loop and backwords logic

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I have a problem developing formula to calculate following logic in Excel. I need to identify patients visits within 30 days interval and then within the identified 30 days interval the most latest date for prescribed medication. 
lets say patients first visit was on 18Dec2018, this should count as New visit. so all visits until 18Jan2019 are considired as within 30days visits. This calculation I have solved nicely with this formula.

```
=OM(OCH(ELLER(C3=C2;C3=C4);ANTAL.OM(C:C;C3)>1;ANTAL.OM(C$2:C3;C3)>1;DAGAR(A3;A2)<30;DAGAR(A3;A4)<30;DAGAR(A:A;A3)<30);"Within 30dgr";"New Visit")
```

And I get in Kolumn G.

No I however within period 18Dec to 18 Jan need to identify latest date for Recepee Registered Date which is available in Kolumn F and I got stack which formula even to start with trying.

[image]

Comment: You will have better luck if you translate the formula into it English equivalents.

Comment: That would be `=IF(AND(OR(C3=C2,C3=C4),COUNTIF(C:C,C3)>1,COUNTIF(C$2:C3,C3)>1,DAYS(A3,A2)<30,DAYS(A3,A4)<30,DAYS(A:A,A3)<30),"Within 30dgr","New Visit")`, helping a hand because it's the weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your problem, there is a small error in your formula - the last row should not be New Visit since the difference is less than 30.

To keep things understandable, I have created 1 extra column as described below:

[image]

1. Date Difference from latest new entry:  this will be

a. 0 if - first entry of patient ;

b. difference between row's date - previous new entry date

c. reset when the difference exceeds 30 - for ex: in row 5 the diff > 30 thus in row 6 it gets reset and the difference is calculated between row6 and row5 instead of row6 and row1

2. Unique Visit: marks whether the visit is new or within 30 days

Formula for date difference(put in row 1):

```
=IF(D2<>D1,0,IF(I1="New",B2-B1,B2-B1+H1))
```

Formula for Unique Visit:

```
=IF(D2=D1,IF(H2<30,"Within 30","New"),"New")
```

Put these formulas in first row and drag down to auto-fill.

3. Latest Recipee Register Date: Captures Recepee register date if the entry is last in entry of 30 days.

Formula:

```
=IF(D2<>D3,G2,IF(I3="New",G2,""))
```

Note: I see that your data is sorted with respect to date and other dates are sorted in ascending order as well. These above formulas will work when the data is sorted in ascending order for the all the dates. For other sorting the formulas will need to change.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for kind advises. I have tried Jay's formula and it worked. However one more stupid question. I I would need to return the latest relevant rate to the row for the first visit. is there any easy way? It would be necessary for getting understanding time discrepancies between first visits and prescriptions.